# IIS 6 ASP.NET handlers not working in virtual application

Tags: asp.net, httphandler

I have a virtual directory (configured as an application). It will accept requests for all files that exist, but it will not call handlers (system.web/httpHandlers).

Any ideas?

```
    <httpHandlers>
        <remove verb="*" path="*.asmx"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*.asmx" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="*" path="*_AppService.axd" validate="false" type="System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptHandlerFactory, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
        <add verb="GET,HEAD" path="ScriptResource.axd" type="System.Web.Handlers.ScriptResourceHandler, System.Web.Extensions, Version=3.5.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35" validate="false"/>
        <add verb="GET" path="*.smjs" type="SmartMax.SightMax.AgentInterface.JSHandler, SmartMax.SightMax.AgentInterface, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b9f7c69b7e2ca2dc"/>
        <add verb="GET" path="*.smgif" type="SmartMax.SightMax.AgentInterface.GifHandler, SmartMax.SightMax.AgentInterface, Version=6.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b9f7c69b7e2ca2dc"/>
    </httpHandlers>
```

this is the url that the application uses.

http://www.datalineonline.com/SightMaxAgentInterface/chat.smgif?accountID=1&siteID=1&queueID=2

Comment: So other .NET components work, like aspx/ascx?

Comment: Yes, everything else works, except for the http handlers (which have custom extensions, like .smgif or something).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With IIS6, i think you have to map the two extensions smjs/smgif to the .net framework. Which i think is C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v2.0.50727\aspnet_isapi.dll, well the same one that aspx is mapped to anyway. Otherwise IIS just rejects the requests.

Or you can map all requests to asp.net

https://serverfault.com/questions/102695/iis6-wildcard-mapping-to-asp-net-no-file-extension-results-in-iis-404

Comment: I checked the mappings and they already exist (installed by sightmax automatically probally). Still no luck.

Comment: can you use firebug and post what the error is when accessing the handler. (eg http://url/virtual/test.smjs)

Comment: and what is the error message you get when you try to access that url? 404, 500?

Comment: HTTP Error 404 - File or directory not found. Internet Information Services (IIS)